# For redirecting standard output in kdb, how to direct everything but results?

Tags: logging, kdb

So for a query function, it product tables. How do I redirect standard output without returning the result? I want to redirect standard output without redirecting the table results. I want to catch every messages kdb produces.

So I tried this

```
q abc.q -p 4000 < /dev/null > kdb.log 2>&1 &.
```

but it also redirect the results from queries, right?

If only direct errors, that doesn't catch everything, right? I want to catch everything but the result.

Comment: Can you give some examples of outputs and where you would like them to be routed?

Comment: i want to redirect everything but tables..results. lets say tab:([]a:1 2 3;b:2 4 6); I do not wanna redirect tab but i don't want it show in q console either. I want to redirect all errors message and other information to log file. i don't want to log those tables cuz its too big.

Comment: this sounds more like a unix question than a kdb question? KDB outputs to standard out/error as any process does, including results like `show table`, so its up to you to (a) redirect on command line (as you have already done in your example) and (b) use correct channels within q to redirect. You might also want to log .z.p[gs] within q. As an aside, you might get more of a response if you reward your fellow stack colleagues with up-votes ;)

Comment: Hi, how do i do up-vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the below.. (I wrote this for a home project)

```
.logger.on:{[pth]
  if[not ":/"~2#string[pth];-1"\n\tPlease supply absolute path to file; e.g.) .logger.on[`:/path/to/logfile]";];
 .logger.err:hopen `$string[pth],".err";
 .logger.std:hopen `$string[pth],".out";
 writeOut:{ h:(.logger.std;.logger.err)x~`err; h(y,"\n");};
 zpi:{y:-1_y; r:@[value;y;{"Error:'",x}]; $["Error:"~6#r;[e:6_r;x[`err;e];-1 e];[x[`std;y];show r]];}[writeOut;];
 `.z.pi set zpi;
 }
```

After loading into q, type some commands...

```
q).logger.on[`:/home/chromozorz/q/projects/myLog]
q)2+2
4
q)1+1
2
q)t:([] a:til 5;b:5?`2)
q)2+string
'type
q)2+`a
'type
q)\\
```

Now check out the created log files;

```
chromozorz@chromozorz:~/q/projects$ cat myLog.err
'type
'type
chromozorz@chromozorz:~/q/projects$ cat myLog.out
2+2
1+1
t:([] a:til 5;b:5?`2)
```

If you don't want to show the result in the console then just edit the zpi definition...